# Для чего используется namespace patch?

Tags: c++, namespace

```
namespace patch
{
    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n )//???
    {
        std::ostringstream stm ;//???
        stm << n ;
        return stm.str() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Объявляется пространство имен `patch`. Так что `to_string` в нем не будет путаться с `to_string` из других пространств имен, так как его полностью квалифицированное имя - `patch::to_string`.

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "для чего используется автомобиль фольксваген". Вопрос не ясен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы в клиентском коде нужно было писать `path::to_string` и таким образом вызов этой версии явно бы отличался от вызовов стандартной `std::to_string`.

Могу предположить, что автор пытался задействовать перегрузки опреатора `std::ostream & operator << (...)` внутри `to_string`, так как стандартаная версия печатает весьма [ограниченый набор типов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).